# Cannot select the edges I want to work with to join them

Tags: mesh, edges

I'm working on a really simple shape that fold round so I've extruded some edges. I now want to join the mesh. I try to select the two edges. I select one and ctrl-lmb the other and it does some kind of loop select. All I want to do is fill the space with a face or maybe attach the two  the edges together. How would I do this?

Comment: hello could you please show some pictures?

Comment: Use _Shift_ + Mouse Click to multiple select (Instead of Ctrl).

Comment: Ctrl + Mouse Click connects the two edges along the closest path so will select all the edges along that path.  As @ChristopherBennett says, you want Shift-Click to select two edges. If you want to connect the edges by a face just press F when they're selected.